# How to reach Out Stack from the island of Unst (Shetland, Scotland)?

Tags: uk, transportation, sea-travel, scotland

I would like to reach or at least sail by the northernmost point in the UK. This is [Out Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_Stack), an uninhabited rock north of the island of Unst, Shetland, Scotland. It is possible to see Out Stack from the north coast of Unst, although getting there requires a four to five hour hike.

Wikitravel [claims](https://wikitravel.org/en/Out_Stack) one can get to Out Stack by fishing boat, but it fails to identify where fishermen hang around.

Back in 2012 [there seems](http://unst.org/web/unstfest2012/2012/06/04/muckle-flugga-boat-trips/) to have been bird watching tours that went to Muckle Flugga, just 600 m south of Out Stack. But [the website](https://www.muckleflugga.co.uk/) of the tour company looks down.

I'm on Unst right now. Any tips on doing this?

Comment: I would just ask anyone on Unst. From my experience the community there is so small that if there's such a thing, most people will know about it. If you are staying at the hotel in Baltasound, I'm pretty sure the owner would be able to help you. Also note that the [wikivoyage article](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Unst) on Unst is much more up to date than the wikitravel one and might be helpful when finding your way around Unst. (I personally updated it after my trip there in 2016)

Comment: You might try connecting with the [Unst Angling Club](https://www.facebook.com/unstanglingclub/) or [Unst Boating Club](http://www.communitydirectory.shetland.gov.uk/unst-boating-club-i230.html), Here's an old [directory](http://www.unst.org/Unst%202007.pdf), no guarantee the numbers will still work.

Comment: Doing is Shenmue style and wandering around town asking for sailors (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQa3yGXzGls) is pretty cool and old school..... But I think Giorgio has the right idea in getting in touch online first. Will be easier to organise in advance.

Answer (score 8):

In the late 70s or early 80s getting out to Muckle Flugga, Out Stack, Foula, Sule Skerry or any of the bird sanctuaries, there were a number of skippers who would take you if you were part of, or associated with Greenpeace.

With the greater focus on protecting these reserves, it has become much harder to visit them, and the occasional tours have all but gone, so for your current visit, as you are on Unst already, your best option is to go to Haroldswick and ask at the boat haven there. Assuming the weather is appropriate, you should be able to find someone who will quote you a cost to sail past the Stack.

Be aware that there are a lot of weather and sea conditions that would preclude a journey like this - it gets pretty rough...